# How to bake shadows into an OBJ that already has an MTL? And then re-export it as OBJ

Tags: baking

I have an .OBJ with .MTL exported from https://ephtracy.github.io/

I import it into Blender. What are the steps to bake shadows onto the existing material and export it again as an .OBJ + .MTL (baked)?

I have attempted to follow various tutorials and forum posts. So far, I've tried Smart UV Unwrap and then bake. I think I've gotten baking working, but without the colors/material (it was all gray). Thanks!